# how to get value from datareader

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to get a values from datareader, but there is an error called

```
"No data exists for the row/column".
```

this is my code

```
//select the group where status is active
OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand("select group from tblBillConfig where status=1 group by group",con);
OleDbDataReader dr2 = com2.ExecuteReader();

//int i = Convert.ToInt32(dr2);
string ii = dr2["group"].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(ii);
```

please anyone can help?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your query doesn't return any record then you get that message.
You need to check if there are rows returned and then try to read them....

By the way, I am pretty sure that the word GROUP is a reserved keyword fow everyt SQL database system. To use it you should enclose it in square brakets (but that could be different for every database system)

```
OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand("select [group] from tblBillConfig " + 
                                     "where status=1 group by [group]",con);
OleDbDataReader dr2 = com2.ExecuteReader();

// This will load the first row, so you could get its value
if(dr2.Read())
{
    string ii = dr2["group"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(ii);
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Query doesn't return any rows");
}
```